# Flutter web fcm messages is recieved from console but not when using rest api

Tags: flutter, web, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hope someone can assist.  Been struggling now for about 2 weeks to get the fcm push notification working on flutter web app.  Using flutter 3.0.7.

I created a firebase project and set it up with cli and recieved a firebase_options.dart file with the web options.  Then created a firebase-messaging-sw.js file.

When testing from firebase console I recieve a message.  But as soon as I use the rest api to send a message it shows it send the message but no message is recieved.  It show the following

FCM request for web sent!
{"multicast_id":3383324657233668851,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}
]}
FCM request for web sent!
{"multicast_id":5796359055236685312,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}
]}

I use the following to send the message after getting the registered key of the device I would like to send to

```
sendPushMessageToWeb(String? token) async {
final endpoint = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
final header = {
```

'Authorization': 'key=7rZmxGEjVqGk0JPi0Fospb0Us47eIn8IqIDeobU8KGFbMoAYTZ-',
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};
http.post(
Uri.parse(endpoint),
headers: header,
body: jsonEncode({
"to": "${token}",
"notification": {"body": "YOUR NOTIFICATION BODY TEXT", "title": "YOUR NOTIFICATION TITLE TEXT", "sound": "default"}
})
)
print('FCM request for web sent!');
}
It looks like it complains about the registration key but using that same key in console works.

Why would it send and recieve message from console but not from rest api?  I did not made any changes in my index.html file for the code lab I used at first and is unable to find again after all my searches did not mension anything about the changes and the console messages is recieved.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

My own mistake for not thinking.  I never checked the length of the token.  The variable on my php mysql was only 100 long but the token is longer than that.  Thank you.

Comment: I'll also keep this in mind, in case I run into the same issue.